# how to resolve this error -- while compiling socketcan utilities

Tags: linux, can-bus, socketcan

I have downloaded  from SVN can utilities. Because by default can utitlities are not in kernel.

```
svn checkout svn://svn.berlios.de/socketcan/trunk/can-utils
```

Kernel i am using is :--

```
ignite@ignite:~/socketcan/can-utils$ uname -a
Linux ignite 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:32:08 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Then i recompiled the utitilities. Here is the error isotp.h not found :---

```
ignite@ignite:~/socketcan/can-utils$ make all
cc -O2 -Wall -Wno-parentheses -I../kernel/2.6/include -fno-strict-aliasing -DSO_RXQ_OVFL=40 -DPF_CAN=29 -DAF_CAN=PF_CAN    isotprecv.c   -o isotprecv
isotprecv.c:60:29: fatal error: linux/can/isotp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [isotprecv] Error 1
cc -O2 -Wall -Wno-parentheses -I../kernel/2.6/include -fno-strict-aliasing -DSO_RXQ_OVFL=40 -DPF_CAN=29 -DAF_CAN=PF_CAN    isotpsend.c   -o isotpsend
isotpsend.c:60:29: fatal error: linux/can/isotp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [isotpsend] Error 1
cc -O2 -Wall -Wno-parentheses -I../kernel/2.6/include -fno-strict-aliasing -DSO_RXQ_OVFL=40 -DPF_CAN=29 -DAF_CAN=PF_CAN    isotpsniffer.c   -o isotpsniffer
isotpsniffer.c:61:29: fatal error: linux/can/isotp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [isotpsniffer] Error 1
cc -O2 -Wall -Wno-parentheses -I../kernel/2.6/include -fno-strict-aliasing -DSO_RXQ_OVFL=40 -DPF_CAN=29 -DAF_CAN=PF_CAN    isotptun.c   -o isotptun
isotptun.c:69:29: fatal error: linux/can/isotp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [isotptun] Error 1
cc -O2 -Wall -Wno-parentheses -I../kernel/2.6/include -fno-strict-aliasing -DSO_RXQ_OVFL=40 -DPF_CAN=29 -DAF_CAN=PF_CAN    isotpserver.c   -o isotpserver
isotpserver.c:80:29: fatal error: linux/can/isotp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [isotpserver] Error 1
make: Target `all' not remade because of errors.
```

Comment: Berlios is very old resource. Please take the newest [can-utils](https://gitorious.org/linux-can/can-utils/source/16c970d40e6c19dde705bad4751bab1a3a4f3a0d:) See this [wiki](http://elinux.org/CAN_Bus) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Clone the latest [can-utils](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils) repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils.git
cd can-utils
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: This is not accessible anymore, its now available on https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils.git